# ESLint - rules that avoid unnecessary `var that = this` pattern

Tags: javascript, eslint

Before the arrow function is introduced, it was quite common to assign `this` to a variable that is used inside a callback. for example, with JQuery, people may write:

```js
/* Omit the definition of `App` */

App.prototype.init = function () {
    var that = this;

    $(`#btn`).on("click", function () {
        that.popUpDialog("Hello!");
    });
}
```

Now since we have arrow function, most of the time we just don't need to write such verbose codes - we can simply use `this` inside the function body, so I think if ESLint has a rule that bans all unnecessary `this` assignments, in order to keep the codes clean and readable.

Comment: Could you provide the exact wording of the ESLint warning.

Comment: Maybe [this existing rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) would help.

Comment: Would you never need both `this` and `that` in the same function? A rule like this seems a little limiting and not drastically tidier (Though perfectly valid if it fits your codebase)

Comment: @dbs that's exactly one unusual but useful use case of `that=this` !!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is the `consistent-this` rule. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/consistent-this

However that is used to

> "enforce consistent naming when capturing the current execution
> context"

Not to explicitly prevent its use.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `consistent-this` with an arbitrary unused placeholder name:

```json
"consistent-this": ["error", "placeholder for invalid variable name"]
```